# For GROUP_CONCAT, "\n" is interpreted as space

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'd like to have each of the concatenated results in a new line (results format HTML). I use something like that:

```
(Group_Concat(DISTINCT ?result; separator = '\n ') as ?results)
```

However, both `\n` and `\r` are interpreted as space, while using any normal character works fine.

As I remember getting what I expected in dbpedia with `\n`, let me also add that I'm currently using 07.20.3214 version of VOS (in case it's a matter of configuration).

---

(added later)
This is in response to the suggested usage of `<br>`. Here's a query for dbpedia, which works with `\n` but with `<br>` it doesn't:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX o: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>

SELECT DISTINCT  ?name  
                 ?wikipedia_page 
                 ?description 
                 (Group_Concat(DISTINCT ?influencer; separator = '\n') as ?influenced_by) 
                 (Group_Concat(DISTINCT ?_influenced; separator = '\n') as ?influenced) 

WHERE {

 {?person rdf:type o:Philosopher ;
         rdfs:label ?label;
     o:influencedBy/rdfs:label ?influencer.}

OPTIONAL {?person o:influenced/rdfs:label ?_influenced.}

 ?person ^foaf:primaryTopic ?wikipedia_page .
FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") .
FILTER (lang(?influencer) = "en").
FILTER (lang(?_influenced) = "en").


OPTIONAL {?person o:abstract ?abstract .
FILTER (lang(?abstract) = "en") .}

BIND (str(?label)  AS ?name)
BIND (str(?abstract)  AS ?description)

}

GROUP BY ?name  ?wikipedia_page ?description
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: separator = '<br>'  may work, but may requiere some extra work, depending on how you output this result.

Comment: This isn't a sparql issue.  A newline in html doesn't mean a newline in the rendered document.  If you want a newline, like Luis said, use "<br>"as the separator.

Comment: Please see my response added in the question itself as I wanted to provide an example.

Comment: "latest version of VOS" is not a useful description. Please provide the explicit version details, so it's clear.

Comment: @TallTed Thanks. Done.

Comment: As noted in my revised answer, 7.20.3215 is currently "the latest VOS."

Answer (score 2):

As @LuisSiquot and @JoshuaTaylor said in comments, the issue here is in neither SPARQL nor Virtuoso, but in your HTML result format.

White space (including `\n`, `\r`, , `\t`, and others) is not guaranteed to be preserved in HTML rendering.  Indeed, they are specified to be collapsed to a single space by any compliant renderer -- which you are apparently using.

`<br>` is the HTML standard line break, and is what I would expect to work as the separator.  It appears that Virtuoso is escaping the angle-brackets of this string when presenting the end result as an HTML table; that may be a bug, or your goal may require a different approach.

ETA: Your `7.20.3214` is not the latest VOS. As of 2015-11-06, VOS has been at `7.20.3215`, and this is the version hosting DBpedia. [Running your query there](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20o%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%3Fname%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdescription%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Group_Concat(DISTINCT%20%3Finfluencer%3B%20separator%20%3D%20'%5Cn')%20as%20%3Finfluenced_by)%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Group_Concat(DISTINCT%20%3F_influenced%3B%20separator%20%3D%20'%5Cn')%20as%20%3Finfluenced)%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%7B%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20o%3APhilosopher%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20o%3AinfluencedBy%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Finfluencer.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20o%3Ainfluenced%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3F_influenced.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%3Fperson%20%5Efoaf%3AprimaryTopic%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Flabel)%20%3D%20%22en%22)%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Finfluencer)%20%3D%20%22en%22).%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3F_influenced)%20%3D%20%22en%22).%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20o%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Fabstract)%20%3D%20%22en%22)%20.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ABIND%20(str(%3Flabel)%20%20AS%20%3Fname)%0D%0ABIND%20(str(%3Fabstract)%20%20AS%20%3Fdescription)%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fname%20%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20%3Fdescription%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on), I see the linefeeds in the HTML source of [the results page](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=PREFIX%20rdf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20o%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dcterms%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20dc%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Felements%2F1.1%2F%3E%0D%0APREFIX%20foaf%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%3Fname%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fdescription%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Group_Concat(DISTINCT%20%3Finfluencer%3B%20separator%20%3D%20'%5Cn')%20as%20%3Finfluenced_by)%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(Group_Concat(DISTINCT%20%3F_influenced%3B%20separator%20%3D%20'%5Cn')%20as%20%3Finfluenced)%20%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%7B%3Fperson%20rdf%3Atype%20o%3APhilosopher%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20o%3AinfluencedBy%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3Finfluencer.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20o%3Ainfluenced%2Frdfs%3Alabel%20%3F_influenced.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%3Fperson%20%5Efoaf%3AprimaryTopic%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Flabel)%20%3D%20%22en%22)%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Finfluencer)%20%3D%20%22en%22).%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3F_influenced)%20%3D%20%22en%22).%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0AOPTIONAL%20%7B%3Fperson%20o%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20.%0D%0AFILTER%20(lang(%3Fabstract)%20%3D%20%22en%22)%20.%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ABIND%20(str(%3Flabel)%20%20AS%20%3Fname)%0D%0ABIND%20(str(%3Fabstract)%20%20AS%20%3Fdescription)%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fname%20%20%3Fwikipedia_page%20%3Fdescription%0D%0ALIMIT%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on), but the rendering in my browser makes those into spaces, as expected.

Comment: Indeed that seems logical, but when put "<br>", I get litarally "<br>" as a separator, and not line. The same happens when I try it on another enpoint, e.g. dbpedia. But what is interesting is that in dbpedia "\n", while "<br>" doesn't, giving the same what I get in my internal endpoint.

Comment: This comment changes your question significantly…  Possibly, you've found a bug; possibly, there's something else going on.  As with any Virtuoso-specific question, I (employed by OpenLink Software) suggest you raise the question in Virtuoso-specific arenas -- the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the public [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), a confidential [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). Be sure to include your Virtuoso's complete version!

Comment: @velitchkov do you mean the actual results, or how DBpedia's endpoints formats them in a nice HTML table?  I'd be surprised if the actual results are off, but not surprised at all if the HTML rendering escapes HTML that could otherwise break the presented table.

Comment: I mean HTML rendering.